# lstlisting caption problem with xepersian

Tags: listings, captions, xepersian

I am using the `xepersian` and `lstlisting` packages and I am having some trouble with the captions.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Nazli}
%\setlatintextfont{Courier}
\DefaultMathsDigits

\definecolor{customblue}{RGB}{235,241,245}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstdefinestyle{C++Style}{%
  backgroundcolor=\color{customblue},
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen}\textit,
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle={\tiny\lr},
  showspaces = false,
  showstringspaces = false,
  tabsize = 2,
  frame=single,
  xleftmargin=5pt,
  xrightmargin=3pt,
  language =  C++,
  aboveskip = 20pt,
  rulecolor=\color{black},
}

\lstnewenvironment{C++Code}
{
   \lstset{style=C++Style}
}{}

\def\lstlistingname{برنامه}

\begin{document}

%case 1
\begin{LTR}
\begin{C++Code}[caption=\rl{تابع فلان}]
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
\end{C++Code}
\end{LTR}

%case 2
\begin{LTR}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=C++Style,caption=\rl{تابع فلان}]
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{LTR}

\end{document}
```

In case 1, the caption does not apear at all and there is a compile-time warning "text dropped after begin of listing ..."

In case 2, The caption does appear but the orientaion is wrong. The whole caption including the `\lstlistingname #:` bit must be right-to-left.

I tried to use something like:

```
\lstnewenvironment{C++CodeLTR}
{
  \LTR
 {
%    \lstset{style=C++Style}
 }
}{}
% \lstset{style=C++Style}
```

but it doesn't work.

P.S. By the way, in case 1, the style is not applied either.

P.P.S. Would these lines from [listings-xepersian.def](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/listings-xepersian.def) help anyone figure out the problem?

```
\ProvidesFile{listings-xepersian.def}[2014/07/17 v0.3 bilingual captions for listings package]
\def\lstlistingname{\if@RTL برنامهٔ\else Listing\fi}
\def\lstlistlistingname{\if@RTL فهرست برنامه‌ها\else Listings\fi}
\endinput
```

I thought this might be relevant since if I don't explicitly define `lstlistingname`, its value would be equal to Listing. Hence the conditions are not met.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Can the issue be reproduced using fonts from a standard TeX install? If so, you can encourage people to help by adapting your example. If not, a link to some place people can download the fonts would be helpful.

Comment: I don't think this is a font issue. However, you can find these fonts in [fonts-farsiweb](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/fonts-farsiweb) and [fonts-liberation](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/fonts-liberation) deb packages.

Comment: I'm not saying it is a font issue. But your code cannot be compiled to reproduce the issue as it stands unless people happen to have the fonts. The more things people have to do in order to reproduce the problem, the less likely they are to work on your question and the less likely you are to get helpful answers. You want to make it as easy as possible for people to help. For example, there is no reason to use Liberation Serif rather than a Latin Modern face, which everyone with a standard TeX installation has. If you can't reproduce without the other font, link the ***upstream*** source.

Comment: Can't you just use the default fonts and not specify them at all?

Comment: The fonts must be specified. I replaced Liberation Serif with Courier. If you do use non-free fonts you can replace Nazli with Arial or something similar. Or you might want to download [Free Persian Font](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpf/).

Comment: If you know of any standard TeX fonts that support Persian/Arabic, let me know and I'll use them.

Comment: Upstream for [Liberation fonts](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/). Nazli does not have a homepage.

Comment: You certainly do ***not*** need to specify a font for Latin scripts. `xpersian` already sets a default which all standard TeX installations include. If you must set one, pick something in standard TeX distributions. Why make it hard for people to help you? Users on some systems won't have Courier. Users on others won't have Liberation Serif. Delete that line and it doesn't matter. Use something we all have and it doesn't matter.

Comment: `Language 'Parsi' not available for font 'Nazli' with script 'Parsi'.`

Comment: Presumably it is not in the type1 versions which is all TeX Live has in the current edition. Since I don't know where to get the fonts, I can't really do much with this. (My distribution doesn't seem to have them and I'm not using a Debian-derivative so I can't use those packages at all straightforwardly. I'd have to get tools to read them and use that to establish the upstream source, I guess. And then create a package for my system.)

Comment: You were right. I commented that line out. A deb package is an [ar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) archive and can be opened by an archive manager. The fonts are in usr/share/fonts/truetype/farsiweb/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the environment up to accept an optional argument if you wish to use one. (This problem has nothing to do with the direction of typesetting.) There is an example on page 42 of the manual for `listings`.

However, to get the caption typeset correctly, you need to look at page 18 of the manual for `bidi` which explains the problem and its solution specifically for the case you are interested in i.e. RTL caption (such that generic name -> number -> colon -> specific name) with LTR code box. For this, `bidi` provides an additional key for `listings`, `captiondirection` which you may set to one of three values: `RTL`, `LTR` or `textdirection`. Since you need to switch to LTR to typeset the code, but want to retain RTL for the captions, you want to use `RTL` to override the current direction of typesetting.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Noto Kufi Arabic}%{PakType Naqsh} http://code.google.com/p/noto/
\DefaultMathsDigits

\definecolor{customblue}{RGB}{235,241,245}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstdefinestyle{C++Style}{%
  backgroundcolor=\color{customblue},
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen}\textit,
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle={\tiny\lr},
  showspaces = false,
  showstringspaces = false,
  tabsize = 2,
  frame=single,
  xleftmargin=5pt,
  xrightmargin=3pt,
  language =  C++,
  aboveskip = 20pt,
  rulecolor=\color{black},
  captiondirection=RTL,
}

\lstnewenvironment{C++Code}[1][]
{%
  \lstset{style=C++Style, #1}%
}{%
}

\def\lstlistingname{برنامه}


\begin{document}

  %case 1
  \begin{LTR}
    \begin{C++Code}[caption={تابع فلان}]
      int main()
      {
        return 0;
      }
    \end{C++Code}
  \end{LTR}

  %case 2
  \begin{LTR}
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=C++Style,caption=\rl{تابع فلان}]
      int main()
      {
        return 0;
      }
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{LTR}

\end{document}
```

Note that I don't have a font on this computer which supports the right script and includes a colon, so the boxes below are actually colons.

[image: captions in RTL]

Since this uses `caption`, it should do all the normal things e.g. get added to the list of listings etc.

Comment: Thanks. This solves half of the problem. The remaining issue is that the `lstlistingname`, the caption number and the colon appear at the far left. You see the whole caption must be left-to-right oriented. Did you read the P.P.S.?

Comment: @Furihr Is this any better? Note that I have no idea what I'm typesetting so I have no intuitive sense of what it should look like. (I can't look at it and 'see' whether things are coming out in the right order because I don't attach any meaning to the different elements of the caption.)

Comment: There is just one thing. If we use `title` instead of `caption`, the entries do not appear in the `\lstlistoflistings`. Can we do anything about that? Redefine `\lstlistoflistings` maybe?

Comment: Should I mark this as solved and ask a new question for the `\lstlistoflistings` problem?

Comment: @Furihr I don't know. Maybe. I'm not very familiar with the package. Perhaps first try posting a message in chat with a link to the question?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `tocloft` package? I thought something like `\newlistof` could be used. I'll try the chat, anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @Furihr The thing is, I can't help but think that there must be a way of doing this cleanly without abusing `title`. The code looks as if it is RTL-aware. If so, I find it hard to believe that this functionality isn't already there, but I just don't know either the package or RTL language support well enough to have a clue where to look. So I'd be reluctant to bring in another package to paste over what I think is probably a problem created by my abuse of `title`.

Comment: @Furihr I had little luck in chat. However, I think I've got it! See edited answer above and page 18 of the `bidi` manual. Would be great if you could confirm or not as I get a bit disorientated trying to figure out if things have come out correctly due to my ignorance of the language.

Comment: It is almost perfect. The only problem is that the caption numbering in the listoflistings is reverse (e.g. It must be 4.1 but it shows 1.4). I have chapters and sections, you see? Sorry that was not in my example.

Comment: @Furihr I think that might be best as a follow-up question because it is going to involve the typesetting of the ToC, basically. (That is, I'm assuming that the list of listings is basically a ToC variant.) So post an example which creates numbering of that kind, and give a link to this question as well.