# Listings package does not return the expected output

Tags: listings, lyx

So I was trying to use the `listings` package for `LyX` in order to create something as following:

[image]

After some research ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147754/listing-package-only-outputs-black-colored-source-code-even-though-the-language)) I saw a suggestion to do the following steps:

In `settings->LaTeX Preamble` I added the following code:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
```

Then I created a `TeX` box and added the following code:

```
\L {
    \lstset{
    tabsize=3,
    frame=shadowbox,
    rulesepcolor=\color{gray},
    xleftmargin=20pt,
    framexleftmargin=15pt,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    emphstyle={\color{magenta}}
}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    def some_function(parameter):
        a_random_number = parameter - 10
        print "some random string" + str(a_random_number)
    # And a random comment!
    if __name__ == '__main__'
        print 'Hello Latex Listings package'
        some_function(20)
    \end{lstlisting}
}
```

Please notice that I use `L{}` because my `LyX` is defined RTL (to support hebrew).

I compile with `pdflatex` and get the following output:

[image]

What should I add/change in order to get the expected output? I don't really care about the highlight per language.

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted your code, suppressed the \L, added a documentclass and send it to pdflatex. And I got something perfect.[image]

I do no use Lyx, but I doubt it can be a problem. Maybe an interaction with RTL. Listings seem to require to be in a LTR environement (see [lstlisting caption problem with xepersian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222590/lstlisting-caption-problem-with-xepersian)). Try to change that.